# Using EDK with framework

Tags: ios, static-libraries, marmalade, ios-frameworks, marmalade-edk

I am trying to implement Mopub in my game. Since Mopub gives their complete source code, I've to compile it into static library.
The Static libraries are giving too much trouble while making the extension. And it always takes me 4-7 days for building a simple extension for iOS. So I was thinking if there's any way I can use a custom framework instead of static library?

Answer (score 0):

Create an edk extension and in the mkf file put `string iphone-link-opts="-framework FrameWorkName"` to deploy section. In extension create function for work with native static library. Framework with static library must be in frameworks path in marmalade or you can define framework path with `iphone-link-opts="-F$MARMALADE_ROOT/modules/frame/work/path -framework FrameWorkName"`.